# RenderAction not finding action method in current controller in current area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, autofac, renderaction

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 2 (RTM) project that uses areas. The Index action of the Home controller of one area needs to use RenderAction to generate a sub-section of the page. The action called is also defined in the same Home controller. So the call should just be:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("List") %>
```

However, I get an exception:

> A public action method 'List' was not found on controller 'RareBridge.Web.Areas.Events.Controllers.HomeController'.

Note that I'm *not* in the "Events" area! I'm in a completely different area. If I remove the "Events" home controller, then the exception still occurs but names a different controller (still not the one I want it to call).

I've also tried providing the controller name and area to the RenderAction method, but the same exception occurs. What is going on here?

BTW: I am using Autofac as my IoC container

Answer (score 15):

Probably action you call has filter attribute (i.e. AcceptVerbs) which doesn't match current request. Remove filters from "List" action and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Use the renderaction overload which takes routeValues as parameter and use the area property to redirect to a specific area:

f.i.

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Edit", module.Value, new { area = "Modules", id = module.Key }); %>
```